# Retrieve roadnames separated by each state HEREapi

Tags: here-api

Is it possible to use calculateroute in HERE api to retrieve roadnames/roadnumbers parsed by each state the route travels through?

Answer (score 0):

Routing API request gives the maneuverattributes(roadname, roadnumber) from origin to destination.

Please refer following link for detailed explanation as per your use case

developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html

Comment: The use case is for analytics/reporting, not actual routing.  What I would like to do is put in an origin and destination and be able to display individually each state and their corresponding roads along the route.  Example: Origin- Chicago, IL  Destination- Columbus, OH.      Output wanted: Illinois: I-90 E, I-94 E, I-80 E ; Indiana: I-80 E, I-65 S, I-865 E, I-70 E, I-670 E ; Ohio: I-670 E, US-33, OH-315 S, US-40